# How do I multiply (square, divide, etc.) a single column in R

Tags: r

```
print(elasticband)
strech distance tension
1     67      148       5
2     98      120      10
3     34      173      15
4     50       60      20
5     45      263      25
6     42      141      30
7     89      166      35
```

So I have this data frame, and I want to be able to alter a single column (For example, square everything in the tension column) without affecting the others like elasticband**2

Any tips?

P.S. I'm not too good at this, so the simpler the fix the better

Answer (score 10):

```
> transform(elasticband, tension2=tension^2)
  strech distance tension tension2
1     67      148       5       25
2     98      120      10      100
3     34      173      15      225
4     50       60      20      400
5     45      263      25      625
6     42      141      30      900
7     89      166      35     1225
```

other alternatives are:

```
elasticband$tension2 <- elasticband[, "tension"]^2
```

Or

```
elasticband$tension2 <-  elasticband$tension^2
```

If you only want a vector as output

```
elasticband[, "tension"]^2
```

Or

```
elasticband$tension^2
```

Comment: Another for good measure: `within(elasticband,tension <- tension^2)`